# kindle fire HDX gmail app

Tags: email, kindle

I am currently using the default email app that came with the kindle fire HDX.  It works 'ok', but it is missing my group email lists I created in chrome.

For example:  I read an article in app xyz and want to share via email to my ten friends.  If I was on my laptop, that would be easy: email address would be my group name.  On kindle, I have to type in each person.

Is there any app that can sync with my gmail from chrome (web based) and give me ability to email to a group of email addresses already setup (i.e. the group name of my ten friends)?  If no app, any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.